# PFFile loading behavior

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pffile

I was wondering how how exactly Parse loads `PFFile` data when you use `getData()` or any of its background equivalents. Here's my case:

I have a `User` class with a key `profilePic`, which is a `PFFile`, in this case a .JPG image. When I load my user I want to display his profile picture into a `UIImageView`. Here's the code I use:

```
let imageFile = user["profilePic"] as PFFile
let imageData = imageFile.getData()
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

I then proceed to set the `image` to the `UIImageView` in a `UITableViewCell`.

As you can see I'm using `getData()` instead of `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock()`, where I would set the `image` in the completion block.

The thing is, I get a warning that I am blocking the main thread, but I notice absolutely no lag whatsoever when I scroll through my table rapidly, thus triggering `getData()` often. I also see no network indicator in the status bar, which would indicate it's pulling the image file from Parse repeatedly.

In summary my question is this: how exactly does parse load my image file when it loads the user? Does it download the image file when it gets all the user info and store it in the cache?  Or does it just load the reference to the file, after which it downloads the file whenever I call `getData()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse downloads a reference to the image file, and when you call [`getData()`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getData) it downloads the contents of the file. When your query is called, all the references are saved (counting as one query). Then, each time you call [`getData()`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getData) it counts as another API request because it needs to go to the server and download the contents of the downloaded reference. [Source](https://www.parse.com/questions/pffile-and-getdata)

If you had a slow internet connection, you might notice problems when you call [`getData()`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getData) on the main thread.

[`getData()`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getData) gets the data from cache if available or fetches its contents from the Parse servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I call `getData()` on the same file multiple times, does it download the file from the server each time, or does it then load from the cache?

Comment: How long does the cache hang around?